# How to use lettrine in Cyrillic?

Tags: cyrillic, lettrine, drop-cap, russian

There are many topics about Latin initial capitals but is it possible to make something similar to that picture in Cyrillic? 
[image]

Comment: I was going to ask whether lettrines have a history in Cyrillic typography, as they do in Latin and French, for instance.  But I guess https://www.facebook.com/photo.php?fbid=937140379654911&set=a.937140319654917.1073742299.100000768734297&type=3&theater is an example.  Can you supply a minimal example, a paragraph you’d like started with a lettrine, and specify a font that’s freely available?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don’t know the language, so there may be problems I haven’t spotted, but it appears that `lettrine` works with the Cyrillic alphabet.  Here’s an example, to be run with `xelatex` or `lualatex`:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a5paper]{book}
\usepackage{fontspec,lettrine}
\setmainfont{PT Serif}
\begin{document}
\lettrine{В}{се} люди рождаются свободными и равными в своем
достоинстве и правах. Они наделены разумом и совестью и должны
поступать в отношении друг друга в духе братства. 
\end{document}
```

[image: output of example]

As egreg notes, `lettrine` can be used with `pdflatex` as well.  But if you find a decorative font to your liking, a Unicode-encoded font in `.ttf` or `.otf`, you can use it very easily in `xelatex` and `lualatex`.  Here, for instance, is [Ruslan Display](http://www.1001fonts.com/ruslan-display-font.html):

```
\documentclass[11pt,a5paper,svgnames]{book}
\usepackage{fontspec,lettrine,microtype,polyglossia,xcolor}
\setdefaultlanguage{russian}
\setmainfont{PT Serif}
\newfontface\init{Ruslan Display}[
  Color=Maroon]
\renewcommand{\LettrineFontHook}{\init}
\renewcommand*{\DefaultLoversize}{.18}
\renewcommand*{\DefaultLhang}{.1}
\begin{document}
\lettrine{В}{се} люди рождаются свободными и равными в своем
достоинстве и правах. Они наделены разумом и совестью и должны
поступать в отношении друг друга в духе братства.
\end{document}
```

[image: output of second example]

Answer (score 2):

I see no problem in using `lettrine` also with `pdflatex`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[russian]{babel}

\usepackage{lettrine}

\begin{document}

\lettrine{К}{}ак и любой читатель, преданный может ясно видеть, идеал
практический разум является представлением, насколько мне известно, все
сами по себе; как я показал в другом месте, явления должны быть лишь
используется в качестве канона для нашего понимания. В алогизмы практическая
Причина есть то, что первый порождают архитектурной практического
Причина. Как будет легко показано в следующем разделе, причина будет
тем самым быть сделаны в противоречие, с учетом этих соображений,
Идеально практического разума, пока многообразие зависит от явлений.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here is simple thing I use:

```
\newfont{\initial}{wcmr17 at 48pt}
\newcommand{\frstltr}[1]{
    \newbox{\litera}
    \savebox{\litera}{\hbox{\initial #1}}
    \vspace*{.2\ht\litera}\par\noindent
    \begin{wrapfigure}{l}{.8\wd\litera}
    \vbox to .05\ht\litera{\vss\usebox{\litera}\vspace*{-.2\ht\litera}}
    \vspace*{-.2\ht\litera}
    \end{wrapfigure}}
```

At beginning of paragraph simply write something like `\frstltr{П}ервая буква`.

**UPD**: working example

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,twoside]{article}
\usepackage[koi8-r]{inputenc}       % Классическая кодировка
\usepackage[english,russian]{babel} % Правила разбиения слов
\usepackage{lipsum}                 % Плавающие картинки и таблицы
\usepackage{wrapfig}                % Обтекаемые объекты
\newfont{\initial}{wcmr17 at 48pt}
\newcommand{\frstltr}[1]{
    \newbox{\litera}
    \savebox{\litera}{\hbox{\initial #1}}
    \vspace*{.2\ht\litera}\par\noindent
    \begin{wrapfigure}{l}{.8\wd\litera}
    \vbox to .05\ht\litera{\vss\usebox{\litera}\vspace*{-.65\ht\litera}}
    \vspace*{-.2\ht\litera}
    \end{wrapfigure}}
\begin{document}
\frstltr{Д}олжно работать!
\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

[image]
<sub>(source: [pic4a.ru](http://pic4a.ru/62/KG.png))</sub>

Comment: I've tried that command but it isn't work right. It puts capital letter on the one line and drops the continuation to the other line.

Comment: @EvgenyLomov, I add working example.